# extract similar record from two tables

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have two tables in access and both conttains numbers (1057, 1045, 4252, etc.)  I would like to pull the similar records that is in both tables.  For instance if table x has record 1057 and table y also includes 1057 than I want to see those records.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*,t2.* from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 on (t1.COMMONCOLUMNID = t2.COMMONCOLUMNID)
```

EDITED

```
select * from TableName where DiscreteUID in (select predecessor from TableName) 
or
DiscreteUID in (select successor from TableName)
```

EDITED

```
    (select DiscreteUID, 1 as IsPredecessor, 0 as IsSuccessor from TableName where DiscreteUID in (select predecessor from TableName))

UNION
    (select DiscreteUID, 0 as IsPredecessor, 1 as IsSuccessor from TableName where DiscreteUID in (select successor from TableName))
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  Sorry but I am new to this what's the difference between t1 and tables1?  Is t1 is the name of column or record?

Comment: that is called aliasing.. instead of writing full table name everywhere, you can give it a 'short' name and use it in its place

Comment: Got you.  So, this is what I have, I have two tables named: Discrete Data and LOE UIDs.  Discrete Data has three columns Discrete UID, Predecessor and Successor.  LOE UIDs has one column LOE UIDs.  I would like to get common records that exist in Predecesor and Successor column with LOE UIDs and Discrete UIDs.  Means, if I have record called 1060 in Discrete UIDs column and in Predecessor column then I would like to see these similar records that matches in both column.  Thanks

Comment: Need to explain better. I didn't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Lets say this.  I have a table with three columns/fields.  I would like to find duplicate or common fields that are in these column.  For instance in table called Discrete UID; I want to take field called Discrete UID and compare this column against Prededecessor field/column and give me all the records that match in both columns/fields.  Thank you

Comment: Is this for a specific input value of DiscreteUID column? ex: You want to know for DiscreteUID value of 1008 you want to get all records where this value is either predecessor or successor. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes but I want to compare one field at a time.  DiscreteUID value of 1008, if that exist in Predecessor than I want to give me that record.  Same goes with Successor, if the value in DiscreteUID exist in Successor column then I want to see that also.  Hope this helps.

Comment: ok. in other words. you want to get all values which have a predecessor or a sucessor. Check my edited answer

Comment: Not sure if we are on the same page.  I want to take field DiscreteUID from table called Discrete Data and compare this field with Predecessor field and if there are any values that exist in both columns then I want to see that.  Same with Successor and DiscreteUID field any common records I want see them.  Sorry don't know how to explain any better than this.

Comment: Brian I used the above query and i think I got something but how can I tell which records are my unique ones that are in both columns (DiscreteUID and Predecessor).  It's giving me all three columns.  Thanks

Comment: Hey I hae to go but I really appreciate your time and help.  Thank you again.

Comment: ok updated. But if a value is both predecessor and successor, it shows up twice. Hope it is ok